# Using postObject

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm a newbie in using RESTKit.

I'm trying to do a simple POST using `postObject`.

I'm wondering if I'm doing this correctly.

I have this block of code :

```
self.gameWebInteractionObject = [[GameWebInteraction alloc] init];
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[mapping mapAttributes:@"id", @"firstname", @"lastname", @"email", @"createdGames", nil];
[self.gameWebInteractionObject.manager.mappingProvider setMapping:mapping forKeyPath:@""];


self.gameWebInteractionObject.manager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[self.gameWebInteractionObject.manager.router routeClass:[UserObject class] toResourcePath:@"/data" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[self.gameWebInteractionObject.manager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[mapping inverseMapping] forClass:[UserObject class]];
[self.gameWebInteractionObject.manager postObject:userobject delegate:self];
```

Comment: Refer this links.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717407/restkit-post-object-and-update-its-attributes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307649/restkit-what-delegate-method-is-called-for-postobject

Answer (score 2):

If you use RestKit 0.20

```
// POST to create
[manager postObject:article path:@"/data" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];

// PATCH to update
[manager patchObject:article path:@"/data/1" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];

// DELETE to destroy
[manager deleteObject:article path:@"/data/1" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

1 is my ID.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit